# C# build date as string with leading 0s and no separators

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date.  I would like to read out all the date parts into separate strings with leading 0s where applicable and then concatenate them to create a date string that is just numbers without any separators.

For example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

string year = dt.Year.ToString();
string month = dt.Month.ToString();
string day = dt.Day.ToString();
string hour = dt.Hour.ToString();
string minutes = dt.Minute.ToString();
string seconds = dt.Second.ToString();

string finalDt = string.Concat(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
```

I would like month to be 01 if it is January, day to be 03 if it is the third day, and likewise with hour, year, seconds.  Is there a way to accomplish that without having to check the count for each datepart and pad it with a leading 0?

If there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do overall, then I would like suggestions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ToString(string format)` for this purpse:

```
dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Or if you still want to do each part separately:

```
string year = dt.Year.ToString("0000");
string month = dt.Month.ToString("00");
string day = dt.Day.ToString("00");
string hour = dt.Hour.ToString("00");
string minutes = dt.Minute.ToString("00");
string seconds = dt.Second.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using custom format-string in the `DateTime.ToString` method:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
```

The `DateTime` type supports many ways of formatting, so you can build up the resulting format from individual "components". Refer to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) to see all the options available.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, fixed :-)